# Choosing between literal map and an existing map using BinCond in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

If an alias has a column consisting of a map,

```
A = LOAD .. AS ( id : int, data : [ DOUBLE ] );
```

and I want to keep the map if the map has at least one element, otherwise I want to replace it with a map [ 'dummy' : 1.0d ].

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE  id, 
                        ( SIZE( data ) == 0 ? TOMAP('dummy', (DOUBLE)1.0) : data ) AS data;
```

This results in the following error,

> Two inputs of BinCond must have compatible schemas. left hand side: #133:map right hand side: udf_results#144:map(#145:double)

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that Pig does not implicitly cast MAP:[ ] to MAP:[ DOUBLE ]. Explicitly casting solved the problem,

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE  id, 
                        ( SIZE( data ) == 0 ? ( ([DOUBLE]) TOMAP('dummy', (DOUBLE)1.0) : data ) AS data;
```